# Undelete directory on openvz server

Tags: openvz, extundelete

Around 1.5 hours ago I deleted a very important directory on my openVZ vps.

I have tried

```
root@server:/home extundelete /dev/simfs --restore-directory ./ --output-dir /home/restore/
extundelete: failed to read-only open device "/dev/simfs": Error code 1
```

How can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

You can't recovery or check a filesystem mounted with read - write privileges.

You will need IMM or physical access to the machine and restart the machine in a maintenance mode or try chaning runlevel to 1, and then run the command umount /.

Another way is to using a live cd to mount and mount read only the partition to recovery your data.

Obviously you will need another place like a pendrive or something to save the files, beucase the main partition will remain read-only until you recovered all files, and remounted it.

**If you really cant stop the server** you can try to create a image file from the disk (but you will need another disk bigger to save it...)

```
dd if=/dev/mygreatdevice of=/mnt/myotherdisk/mygreatimage.img
```

and run the ext4 data recovery on the mygreatimage.img

This can works but the files recovered can be more corrupted than the normal corruption of normally data recovery.